# Does the Android developer console ignore uses-feature android:glEsVersion?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I tried loading an update for my app where I've switched from OpenGL ES 1.0 to 2.0 rendering, and wanted to leave the old version up for devices that don't support 2.0. However, when I tried to activate both APKs at once, the Google Play developer console told me that the two apks target exactly the same devices so they can't be active at the same time.

One of them has this in the manifest, and the other does not:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

So I went over to another app that I have that also uses only ES 2.0, and I noticed that under the APK details, it lists the other features that my manifest requires, but not glEsVersion.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  "Advanced mode" lets you upload multiple simultaneously active APKs, but the only filters used to compare these APKs are screen size, API level, and texture compression format.